# Creating virtual printer for Windows

Tags: printing, driver, virtual

I want to create a Virtual Printer for Windows that will manipulate the page order, pages to print and will be able to pause the print job.

I think that I should create a virtual printer that the user can choose that will manipulate these things, and then print it with another physical printer.

I don't know how to start, because I never worked in drivers level. 
How can I create virtual printer that the computer will think that is physical, and how can I manipulate the job and transfer the job to physical printer..

Comment: Hey @nrofis, Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: @jNewbie Not exactly, I saw that there is a way to create virtual devices with COM Objects, but I didn't found how to create virtual printer

Comment: hey @nrofis, did you got solution to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, no... :(